# Need help in accessing a List in JSP using ModelMap of spring frame work

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, jsp-tags

This is the first time ever iam asking a question over here.

I have to display a list in JSP which is beig access over there using the Spring ModelMap object
The output in form is loop in braces 46 times, 46 times which is the nuber of string in the list.

Please help me in iterating over the List in the JSP. Thanks in Advance.

```
<form:form commandName="dmnListRef" name="DMN_LIST_REF"  method="POST" modelAttribute="dmnListRef" action="DMN_LIST_REF.html">
       <c:forEach items="${dmnListRef.listString}" var="loop">
            <tr>
                 <td>${loop}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
            </form:form
```

I have a Bean

```
public class DmnListRefVO implements Serializable {

    private List<String> listString=new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

And a controler code where iam sedning the lsit to ModelMap

```
private void fillModelData(ModelMap modelMap) {
    logger.debug("==============Entered the fillModelData dmnListRef======\n");
    DmnListRefVO dmnListRef = dmnListRefService.findAllDmnListRef();

    modelMap.addAttribute("dmnListRef", dmnListRef);

    logger.debug("==============Exiting the fillModelData dmnListRef=Lisof Headers===="+dmnListRef.getListString());            
    logger.debug("==============Exiting the fillModelData dmnListRef ModelMap======\n"+modelMap);

}
```

Comment: It seems working perfect, what problem do you have in it?

Comment: The foreach is itearting 46 times..Which is hopefully correct But its not printing the contents of the listString.Instead it is pringting what ever mentioned in the <td>${loop}</td>
For instance loop in the above case...When i print the modelmap in logger inside controller class its printing the list values..But inside JSP not able to access